# Relative path for browsing folder in java

Tags: java

I want to modify to browse the folder through  the relative path.
The code only browse through the absolute path and check only the provided directory is empty or not...plz help....thanks in advance

package fyp;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Frame2 extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame2 frame = new Frame2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Frame2() {
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(92, 107, 272, 20);
    setTitle("Plagiarm Detection System\r\n");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
    btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                chooser.setDialogTitle("Browse the folder to process");
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

               File file=new File("C:/Users/Shahzaib/Desktop/empty");
                //File relative=new File("C:/Users/Shahzaib/Desktop/empty");


               //System.out.println(relative.getName());
               //System.out.println(relative.getPath());


                //File file = new File("directory"); 

                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                {
                    textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
                    //System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+ chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                    //System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "+ chooser.getSelectedFile());


                }
                if(file.isDirectory()){

                    if(file.list().length>0){

                        Component frame = null;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Directory is  Not Empty.");

                    }else{

                        Component frame = null;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Directory is Empty.");

                    }


                //else 
                //{
                  // Component frame = null;
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No Selection.");


                }


            }


        });








        getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);
    btnBrowse.setBounds(374, 106, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnBrowse);

    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnProceed = new JButton("Next");
    btnProceed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
            new Frame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnProceed.setBounds(485, 227, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnProceed);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dispose();
            new Frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnBack.setBounds(374, 227, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnBack);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Choose Folder of Assignments");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(180, 11, 235, 50);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
}
```

}

Comment: i get the folder through absolute path as mentioned   File file = new File("C:/Users/Shahzaib/Desktop/empty");....i want to make it relative but didn't able to do so...plz tell me the solution...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to files usually you at least want to have a `try{}` and `catch{}`.

Hints: if you want to find the directory of a file, try `file.getParent()` or `file.getParentFile()`. Additionally, you should check to see if the file exists `.exists()` or `isDirectory()`.

Comment: I tried this also...but wasn't able to do so....if you review my code...u understand then